# How to set object array back to iterated collection from nested find() in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I develop application using AngularJS , NodeJS and MongoDB. I'd like to load Product with classified by ProductCategoryCode sending from 
AngualrJS to NodeJS. First, I need to find Products by ProductCategoryCode and then iterate for each product to find Uoms by UomCode and ContainUomCode 
which each product should has 2 uoms. How can I set uom object `docUom` back to product document `doc[i]` and update to product collection `doc`?

For following code line

```
doc[i].Uom = docUom;
```

The system throw error cannot set property 'Uom' of undefined.

Here is `product.js` snippet code.

```
router.get("/LoadProductByProductCategoryCode/:productCategoryCode", function (req, res) {
    console.log('user.js -> /users ');
    var productCategoryCode = req.params.productCategoryCode;
    console.log(productCategoryCode );
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
        format = require('util').format;

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/NodeDB', function (err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var query = { ProductCategoryCode : productCategoryCode}
            var new_product = [];
            findProduct(db, query, function (err, doc) {
                if(err) {
                    // something went wrong
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                if (doc) {
                    console.log("Found Product..."+doc.length);
               　    for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
                        console.log(doc[i].ProductCode + " each document " + doc[i].UomCode + " " + doc[i].ContainUomCode);
                        var qUom = { 
                            $or: [ { UomCode: doc[i].UomCode}, { UomCode: doc[i].ContainUomCode } ] 
                        }
                        // Find uom
                        findUom(db, qUom, function(errUom, docUom) {
                            if(errUom) {
                                console.log("error " + errUom);
                                return;
                            }
                            if (docUom) {
                                doc[i].Uom = docUom;
                                console.dir(product);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    res.json(doc);
                } else {
                    console.log('something happen');
                }
            }); //End 
        }); // MongoClient
        var findProduct = function (db, query, callback) {
            db.collection('Product').find(query).toArray(function (err, doc) {
                if(err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
                else {
                    callback(null, doc);
                }
            });
        }
        var findUom = function(db, queryUom, callback) {
            db.collection('Uom').find(queryUom).toArray(function (err, doc) {
            //    db.close();
                if(err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
                else {
                    callback(null, doc);
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Any idea? THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Because of the asynchronous nature of the Node.js MongoDB driver, both the `findProduct()` and `findUom()` methods start, but don't necessarily complete by the time you reach `res.json(doc)` meaning `doc` will still be empty. You are expecting this to work in a linear fashion, but node works differently.

Instead, you should send your response back once all asynchronous calls complete meaning you could try something like:

```
findProduct(db, query, function (err, doc) {
    if(err) {
        // something went wrong
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    var processedProduct = function (item) {
        console.log(item.ProductCode + " each document " + item.UomCode + " " + item.ContainUomCode);
        var qUom = { 
            $or: [ { UomCode: item.UomCode}, { UomCode: item.ContainUomCode } ] 
        }
        // Find uom
        findUom(db, qUom, function(errUom, docUom) {
            if(errUom) {
                console.log("error " + errUom);
                return;
            }
            if (docUom) {
                item.Uom = docUom;
                console.dir(product);
                return item;
            }
        });        
    }   　    
    if (doc) {
        var productsToFind = doc.length;
        var products = [];
        console.log("Found Products..." + productsToFind);        
        for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
            product = doc[i];
            product = processedProduct(product);
            products.push(product);
            productsToFind -= 1;
            if(productsToFind === 0){
                res.json(products);
            }            
        }        
    } else {
        console.log('something happen');
    }
}); //End
```

I could explain better about asynchronous calls and callbacks as this topic is a bit broad but from the above you can get the idea that I have used a counter `productsToFind` for all of the inner async calls that once each `findUom()` call completes this counter decrements and once it reaches 0 it means that all callbacks have fired.

Comment: thanks @chridam.Finally, I've got expected result from your code.

Comment: The output in console is perfect, but when I call the url to display result  in browser it's only has product detail not include uoms. this is related to  async and callback process ?

Comment: @iPatz No, it's because the function processing is just doing a `console.dir(product);`, it's not returning the processed product. I will amend the answer to reflect this and try from there.